# How to access a depthmap value from a depth camera?

Tags: opencv, mat

I am currently using a Depthsense 325 from softkinetics. I am quite new to a depth camera and openCV. I would like to access the depth value in each pixel, therefore, I modified the given consoledemo program a little bit to test the code. The code is as following.

```
 /*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

// New depth sample event handler
void onNewDepthSample(DepthNode node, DepthNode::NewSampleReceivedData data)
{


int32_t w, h;
FrameFormat_toResolution(data.captureConfiguration.frameFormat,&w,&h);



g_dFrames++;



// show depth image
if ( data.depthMap != nullptr ) {
    cv::Mat mat( h, w, CV_16SC1, (void*)(const int16_t*)data.depthMap );        

    cv::imshow( "SoftKinetic Depth Camera", mat );
    cv::waitKey( 1 );
}

  // save depthmap (h =320, w=240)

 cv::Mat test_mat( h, w, CV_16SC1, (void*)(const int16_t*)data.depthMap );
 cout << "rows: " << test_mat.rows << endl;
 cout << "col: " << test_mat.cols << endl;
 printf("%d \n",test_mat.at<short>(0,0));


}
```

However, it keeps showing the error message: opencv error assertion failed. Anybody please let me know what is wrong with my code. My system is window 7, Microsoft visual studio 2010, opencv 2.4.6

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you try out this version. Replace the line in your code with this one.

```
cv::Mat mat( h, w, CV_8UC1, (void*)(const float*)data.depthMap );
```

Comment: This code is wrong. DepthMap in DepthSense is of type `int16_t`. `CV_8UC1` is 8 bits.